# accessing a Dictionary<Tuple, int>

Tags: c#, dictionary, tuples

Declaration

```
 private Dictionary<Tuple<String, int>, int> securityLevel;
```

Inside Constructor for initialization

```
        securityLevel.Add(Tuple.Create("Agent", 0), 1);
        securityLevel.Add(Tuple.Create("DoubleAgent", 500), 2);
        securityLevel.Add(Tuple.Create("FieldOfficeManager", 2105086), 3);
        securityLevel.Add(Tuple.Create("DivisionChief", 8388350), 4);
        securityLevel.Add(Tuple.Create("RegionalManager", 2104960), 5);
        securityLevel.Add(Tuple.Create("ChiefInformationSecurityOfficer", 6307582), 6);
```

My method

```
 private int getLowestSecurityLevel(Dictionary<Tuple, int> entry)
    {
        int currentSecurity = 0;
        // not sure how to iterate a Dictionary with a Tuple? I want to get the title of the Geek Squad agent
       foreach (KeyValuePair<Tuple<String, int>, int> item in entry)
       {
       }
    }
```

Visual Studio tells me that

> Cannot convert 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair,
>   int>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair'

Comment: "I want to get the title of the Geek Squad agent" - from what? From `currentSecurity = 0` matching against the int in the tuple, i.e. you want "Agent"? If that's the value you need to match, why isn't that int the key of the dictionary instead of the whole tuple? What does the 1-6 represent in the dictionary values?

Comment: @Rup I updated the question to include how I declared it and provided information about how it's initialized

Comment: OK, but that's not what I asked.

Comment: How does `currentSecurity` value belongs to `Tuple<String, int>, int`?

Comment: Well the logic was if the Dictionary that is passed didnt contain any entries then we return 0 otherwise we set the "currentSecurity" to the lowest int. But how it's being used doesn't help me with iterating the Dictionary

Comment: Well iterating a dictionary is going to be the same with or without the tuple? `foreach(var dictionary_entry in entry) { ... }` and `dictionary_entry` will have a `Key` property that will be your tuple and a `Value` property that will be the number 1-6. Note that you will not get these back in the order you inserted them, so you might need to OrderBy them first, or take care as you iterate through.

Comment: OK, so your goal is to find one of the ints from your dictionary? Which one? The one in the tuple (e.g. 0, 500, 2105086 etc.) or the one in the entry value (1-6)?

Comment: "Visual Studio tells me that" - yes, that's because you didn't specify the types in your `Dictionary<Tuple, int> entry` parameter, as a few of the answers below said. `entry` is a dictionary of generic tuples; your foreach parameter is trying to get a typed Tuple.

Comment: If that "Agent" line is temporarily removed (because the values are too simple), what would be the value you want to return? Can you explain *why*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Tuple Deconstruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct)

```
private void GetLowestentry(Dictionary<Tuple<string, int>, int> entry)
            {
                int currentSecurity = 0;

                foreach(KeyValuePair<Tuple<string, int>, int> keyValue in entry)
                {
                    // Your condition
                    if(keyValue.Key.Item1 == "Your Name")
                    {
                        // Select Anything you want
                        currentSecurity = keyValue.Key.Item2;
                        //currentSecurity = keyValue.Value;
                    }
                }

         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare your dictionary as:

```
Dictionary<(string, int), int>
```

This will use the new tuple support in C#. The old `Tuple` class should be avoided these days, and the language has built in support for the new `ValueTuple` structure.

Add the values like this:

```
securityLevel.Add(("Agent", 0), 1);
securityLevel.Add(("DoubleAgent", 500), 2);
securityLevel.Add(("FieldOfficeManager", 2105086), 3);
securityLevel.Add(("DivisionChief", 8388350), 4);
securityLevel.Add(("RegionalManager", 2104960), 5);
securityLevel.Add(("ChiefInformationSecurityOfficer", 6307582), 6);
```

And change your method to:

```
private int getLowestSecurityLevel(Dictionary<(string, int), int> entry)
```

Comment: why? would I need to change the way I constructed the item?

Comment: And how would that help the OP to get at the wanted (mostly unspecified) answer?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to match `int currentSecurity = 0;` against

```
securityLevel.Add(Tuple.Create("Agent", 0), 1);
```

then you want

```
string title = entry.Keys.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Item2 == currentSecurity)?.Item1;
```

(or SingleOrDefault). However this isn't using a dictionary properly. If you need to look up the strings by this number, the second in the tuple, then you should make that the dictionary key, i.e.

```
var securityLevel = new Dictionary<int, string>();
securityLevel.Add(0, "Agent");
```

assuming you don't need that extra int 1 that you're currently saving as the value in the dictionary for this tuple.